# DHCP Broadcast on SVI

Tags: vlan, dhcp, layer2, interface, broadcast

Think of a dhcp broadcast going through multiple switches. What happens to that broadcast when it reaches the vlan interface (svi)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the switch config, the SVI can have a DHCP server or relay (helper) running on it. Then it would reply to the discovery or relay it to the DHCP server.

Without a DHCP config on the switch the frame is ignored/dropped (on the SVI - the switch port still forwards the frame across the broadcast domain).